# Web API returning HttpResponseMessage object after nuget updates in Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, nuget, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Web API 5, it's has been working fine, I return a HttpResponseMessage object with `Content = new StringContent("content here")` and get the expected content when calling the API.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetData([FromBody]DataObject input)
    {
      .....
      return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnModel))
            };
    }
```

However, I recently updated a number of MVC and .NET NuGet packages, and now, while the project compiles and runs fine locally, when I deploy to an Azure Web App, calling the API returns the actual HttpResponseMessage object with no content, rather than the content:

```
{
"Version": {
    "_Major": 1,
    "_Minor": 1,
    "_Build": -1,
    "_Revision": -1
},
"Content": {
    "Headers": [
        {
            "Key": "Content-Type",
            "Value": [
                "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"StatusCode": 200,
"ReasonPhrase": "OK",
"Headers": [],
"RequestMessage": null,
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Normally this same call would return a JSON string of the Content object. Is there some odd dependency issue happening, any ideas on how to fix without rolling back all of the nuget updates? Or do I need to update a setting on the Azure Web App (already have .NET 4.7 set).

Comment: Were you able to nail this down at all?  Ran into the same problem yesterday.  Your question got me thinking.  It turned out that installing Polly nuget package did this to all my HttpResponseMessage return values.

Comment: Unfortunately not - we basically had to roll all of our Nuget packages back to before updating :( spent too much time already, so wasn't able to upgrade package by package and figure out what was the issue. If you figure it out, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming an `ApiController`, the action can be refactored to use the more recent advised syntax.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetData([FromBody]DataObject input) {

    //.....code awaited here and gets 'returnModel'

    return Ok(returnModel);
}
```

Comment: Will have to try this out, however refactoring the whole project to move from HttpResponseMessage to IHttpActionResult is unfortunately not possible due to the amount of effort right now.

HttpResponseMessage works locally, just not on an Azure Web App, which is the most confusing part (if the HttpResponseMessage syntax was changed or broken, I'd expect it to be universally so).

Comment: @codechinchilla it was removed from asp.net-core, which had the same behavior that you described above but you indicated that you are on asp.net-web-api5