# After installing Polly for retries, HttpResponseMessage appears to be overridden

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, polly

We've got an ASP.NET Web API 2 app which leverages `HttpResponseMessage` as the return value controller due to our need for send back straight text.  Our code looks something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Submit(string data)
{
    ...do some sutff...
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent("Success", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
    };
}
```

Things work great.  In another area of the codebase, there is a set of methods that need a retries, we installed the Polly nuget package, added in the retry and everything looks great when running locally in Visual Studio.  As soon as we deploy Azure, thing go bad.

When compiling and running localling in Visual Studio debugger we expect and get a 200 response with a simple text string. This issue is when deployed to an Azure Web App. Once we do this our calls to the API all return the following:

```json
{
"Version": {
    "_Major": 1,
    "_Minor": 1,
    "_Build": -1,
    "_Revision": -1
},
"Content": {
    "Headers": [
        {
            "Key": "Content-Type",
            "Value": [
                "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"StatusCode": 200,
"ReasonPhrase": "OK",
"Headers": [],
"RequestMessage": null,
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

If we uninstall Polly, everything goes back to normal.

The only other comment/question we could find out there was the following: [Web API returning HttpResponseMessage object after nuget updates in Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969826/web-api-returning-httpresponsemessage-object-after-nuget-updates-in-azure-web-ap)

2 Questions:

1. What is the response above? My content isn't there and I've never seen this before.
2. Is there something in Polly that I've missed in terms of configuration etc. that might cause this?

Comment: The shown JSON is the serialization of a `HttpResponseMessage`. The deployed web app is most probably using .net-core, which no longer recognizes that object as a valid response but as data

Comment: because of its conversion to .net standard the library will target the common API for the targeted platforms.

Comment: [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the response returned by HttpClient. It's *doesn't* implement IActionResult so it could never be translated as a Web API response, only as a payload. The *local* code shouldn't have worked in the first place

Answer (score 1):

As Nkosi said, this is ASP.net-Core then you are mixing web API versions and on the server side Asp.Net Core **no longer uses** `HttpResponseMessage`.

You need to use the appropriate action result to return the desired data like **ActionResult**.

```
[HttpGet("{id}"]
public ActionResult Submit(string data) {

    //...do some stuff...

    //returns 200 with the content and specified media type for the content
    return Content("Success", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822132/c-sharp-httpresponsemessage-content-does-not-return-memorystream-correctly-to-ht).

Comment: Try adapting your code example to the snippet from their original question

Comment: This is not an ASP.net Core project.  It is .NET Framework 4.6.2.  As mentioned, this runs fine locally but fails when pushed to Azure.  If I was mixing web api versions or similar I would think I would get the same result on Azure.

Comment: Sorry for mistake. But it also the same issue. You could use the ActionResult to return data.

Comment: @DouglasAnderson HttpResponseMessage is an HttpClient response class, *not*  a Web API class. The local code shouldn't work either.